# Why does a generic "factory" create Types different from ones coming from identical inline code?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, gson

I have this simple snippet using Google GSON:

```
 import com.google.gson.reflect.TokenType;
 import java.lang.reflect.Type;
 ...
 Type t1 = new TypeToken<MyClass>(){}.getType();
 Type t2 = typeFor(MyClass.class);
 ...
 private <T> Type typeFor(Class<T> clazz) {
     return new TypeToken<T>(){}.getType();
 }
 ...
 t1.getClass().getCanonicalName(); // "java.lang.Class"
 t2.getClass().getCanonicalName(); // "sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl"
```

Why are the classes not the same?

Comment: Why do you expect them to be the same class?

Comment: @JimGarrison I expect them to be ... similar; the class names are completely different though. They don't seem to share anything in common (e.g. instance fields or sth)

Comment: You are not looking at the types of your objects. You are looking at the types of the types of your objects, i.e. you are effectively calling `getType().getClass()`. The result of that call chain will not describe your objects but the reflection implementation itself.

Comment: @Holger Deep, need to think it through; In the meantime: how to refactor `new TypeToken<MyClass>(){}.getType();` to a method then??

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Holger Well I am suprised, because the same code gives me different results! (inline vs. method). I want to have a single method that returns me types and not `new` the `TokenType` everywhere I need a `Type` ...

Comment: I don’t see the problem. You can use the factory method. Why is it important what `getType().getClass()` returns? If you want to introspect your objects you just need to use `getClass()` without `getType()`. See the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructs are not identical.

By saying `new TypeToken<MyClass>(){}` you are creating a subclass of `TypeToken<MyClass>`. The base class of this anonymous subclass has filled in the concrete type `MyClass` for the type parameter, hence the subclass has no type parameter.

On the other hand the construct `new TypeToken<T>(){}` creates an anonymous subclass of the type `TypeToken<T>` which does not have an argument filled in but depends on the parameter of the factory method. As a consequence, the argument for that type parameter is not fixed for the subclass too, which makes it effectively a class with a type parameter.

Both classes are anonymous subclasses of `TypeToken` and if you invoke the factory method with the type argument `MyClass`, the instances are assignable to `TypeToken<MyClass>` in both cases. But they are different: the factory method can be invoked using different type parameters, your inlined statement is fixed to the specified type argument.

This is reflected when invoking `getType` on the instances. The result of the factory has a type which is parametrizable which is represented an instance of `TypeVariableImpl` while the instance of your inlined code has no type parameter and hence has a type which is identical to its `Class` and therefore represented by the `Class` object itself.

Note that invoking `getClass()` on your `TypeToken` instance directy will return the raw type of your classes which will give you similar results for both constructs, representing an anonymous subclass of `TypeToken`.

Comment: Ok, so how would you solve my problem? I need this Type for Google GSON configuration - associate a deserializer with a class. Now I can manually type `new TypeToken<MyClass>(){}.getType()` everywhere (for each class), but I'd rather have this hidden behind a pleasant method call (the one I coded - `typeFor` - doesn't construct the types expected by GSON)

Comment: Your factory method using a class object as a parameter would never work for generic classes. And for non-generic classes it’s just nonsense— the `TypeToken` class has such a factory method already. Just use [`TypeToken.get(MyClass.class)`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1.1/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html#get(java.lang.Class)).

Comment: and if I had `Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Long>>(){                                 }.getType();` ? It won't work..

Comment: That’s right and as I explained, your factory method won’t work either. You can’t create a `Class` object to represent the type `Map<String, Long>`, i.e. you can’t say `Map<String, Long>.class`, so you can’t pass it to neither your factory method nor the factory method already provided by `TypeToken`. The generic type can be fixed by creating a subclass of a concrete type, that’s what `TypeToken` does and my answer explains. And my answer explains why it doesn’t work with a generic factory method. No solution to it, sorry. If there were another solution, Google had provided it already.